# How to make a DataGridView expandable in C# with a button?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I wan't to make my DataGridView expand on a button click and collapse on the second click. It is because it contains a plenty of rows and I have a little space where my DGV can fit in. So on a button click I want to my DGV to change the height to the half of the form and after a second button click to collapse back where it was.

Comment: Just change the Height Property of the control in the buttons click event? And then look at your form if that really is what you want or you missed some details. Like i want at the same time that other controls move out of the way or something like that.